# is there any symbol that cannot be submitted into a hash function?

Tags: php, hash

Is there any character or symbol that cannot/should not be submitted into any hash function that would throw an error or break the function or anything like it? No characters submitted into a hash need to be escaped or anything right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Hash functions are made to work on binary data, just as well as strings.  There is nothing you need to do to prepare data for hashing.

Comment: okay great! I can't understand why websites would limit special characters/lengths of passwords then if a simple hash allows more or less any password to be database acceptable.

Comment: @Ryan, Unfortunately, not everyone uses hashes in a database.  Plus, there are often external considerations, where a password must be valid in some other back-end system that has these constraints.

Comment: @Ryan Or the cynical explanation: bad programmers think that eliminating special characters from passwords is a good way to prevent SQL injection attacks. And other similarly bogus security measures.

Comment: @JohnKugelman that's more along the lines of what I think anytime I see a site that restricts special characters from passwords